# Composer - .phar and .json file locations - Symfony2

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm trying to install this https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md and I'm following the Composer install advice.

When I installed Symfony2 I also followed the advice and can't fully remember, but I now have this directory structure:

```
files/folder1/folder2/composer.phar
files/folder1/folder2/symfony/composer.json
```

When following the instructions I get this error:

```
Composer could not find a composer.json file in files/folder1/folder2/
```

In other words my composer.json isn't in the same directory as my composer.phar, but this has never been a problem before.

I want to do this properly rather than just move a file, so what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to move your `composer.phar` file. You can run command from directory where is stored your `composer.json`:

```
$ php ../composer.phar update
```

or you can pass working directory as argument to `composer.phar`

```
$ php composer.phar --working-dir=symfony/ update
```